# Unix shell script convert age in number of months

Tags: shell, unix

i want to write shell script which enter the age and convert that age in no. of months;  then as per age display that the person is child,teenager,adult or old aged.

Comment: If that's what you want to do, then do it, what's the problem? If you're having trouble, show us what you tried, explain what it's doing wrong, and someone will help you fix it.

Comment: i am very new to this shell scripts ..so i dont know how to do it i just know sytax of loops and if statement...i know to display ...just having problem how to convert

Comment: Then you need to learn. We don't write your code for you, you have to put some effort in first.

Comment: Your textbook should explain how to do arithmetic in the script. Then use `if` to test if it's in the ranges for child, teenager, adult, or old.

Comment: thank you for your reply...i dont have any text book its out of syllubus..i am trying to learn it on my own...i know simple arithmetic operations and loops etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read here: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html

Here is an example, for checking if an age is a number is a high level school:

```
printf "Enter age: "
read age
if [[ "$age" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] ; then
   months=$(expr $age \* 12)
   echo "$age years is $months months"
   if [ $age -lt 11 ]; then
      echo "child."
   elif [ $age -lt 20 ]; then
      echo "teenager."
   elif [ $age -lt 100 ]; then
      echo "less than 100, and so on..."
   fi
else
   echo "Enter number." 
fi
```

Edit: Barmar points out that expr is an old fashioned method. You can use `let "months=$age * 10"` instead.

Comment: The 1990's called, they want their `expr` back. Modern shells have built-in expression handling.